# Use the Trapezoidal Rule, the Midpoint Rule, and Simpson's Rule:$\int^4_0 e^{3\sqrt{t}} \sin\ 3t\ dt$

Tags: calculus

$$\int^4_0 e^{3\sqrt{t}} \sin\ 3t\ dt$$

(1)

the given integral is

$$I=\int_{0}^{4}e^{3\sqrt{t}}\sin(3t)dt$$

here we have

$a=0, b=4$ and $n=8,$ so

$$\Delta t=\frac{b-a}{n}$$

so,

$$\Delta t=\frac{4-0}{8}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I divided the interval $[0,4]$ into $8$ subintervals with the following endpoints

$[0,1/2],[1/2,1],[1,3/2],[3/2,2],[2,5/2],[5/2,3],[3,7/2]$ and $[7/2,4]$

$$a=0,1/2,1,3/2,2,5/2,3,7/2,4=b$$

**(a)**

**trapezoidal rule**:

according to trapezoidal rule,

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\frac{\Delta t}{2}(f(t_{0})+2f(t_{1})+2f(t_{2})+....+2f(t_{n-1})+f(t_{n}))$$

so,

$f(0)=0$

$2f(1/2)=16.642495$

$2f(1)=5.668942$

$2f(3/2)=-77.065493$

$2f(2)=-38.889819$

$2f(5/2)=215.413258$

$2f(3)=148.837516$

$2f(7/2)=-481.763872$

$f(4)=-216.468965$

so integral is

$$I=\int_{0}^{4}e^{3\sqrt{t}}\sin(3t)dt=\frac{1}{2}(0+16.642495+5.668942-77.065493- \\ -38.889819+215.413258+148.837516-481.763872-216.468965)$$

$$\int_{0}^{4}e^{3\sqrt{t}}\sin(3t)dt=-106.906484$$

**(b)**

**simpson's rule**:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\frac{\Delta t}{3}(f(t_{0})+4f(t_{1})+2f(t_{2})+4f(t_{3})+2f(t_{4})....+4f(t_{n-2})+2f(t_{n-1})+f(t_{n}))$$

so,

- remaining all things all things are same,just we have to put the values of the function at the given endpoints

$f(0)=0$

$4f(1/2)=33.284990$

$4f(3/2)=-154.130985$

$2f(2)=-38.889819$

$4f(5/2)=430.826517$

$2f(3)=148.837516$

$4(7/2)=-963.527744$

$f(4)=-216.468965$

so integral is

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\frac{1/2}{3}(0+33.284990+5.668942-154.130985-38.889819+ \\ +430.826517+148.837516-963.527744-216.468965)$$

$$\int_{0}^{4}e^{3\sqrt{t}}\sin(3t)dt=\frac{1}{6}(0+33.284990+5.668942-154.130985-38.889819+ \\ +430.826517+148.837516-963.527744-216.468965)$$

$$\int_{0}^{4}e^{3\sqrt{t}}\sin(3t)dt=-125.733258$$

**(c)**

**midpoints rule**:

according to midpoints rule

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\Delta t(f(\frac{t_{0}+t_{1}}{2})+f(\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{2})+.....+f(\frac{t_{n-1}+t_{n}}{2}))$$

so,

- remaining all things are same , just put the values at the specified place for the given endpoints,

$f(1/4)=3.054893$

$f(3/4)=10.455640$

$f(5/4)=-16.358023$

$f(7/4)=-45.447797$

$f(9/4)=40.511676$

$f(11/4)=133.537487$

$f(13/4)=-71.335135$

$f(15/4)=-322.709797$

so integral is

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=-134.145527$$

However, my answer is wrong. I only have one more chance. [image]

Comment: I think you are off by a smidget-

Comment: Your last answer is same as the one you marked with a red x, both are -134.145527. But for the simpson's rule the coefficient on the second to last term used is a 4 not a 2. Patterns like 1,4,2,4,1 or 1,4,2,4,2,4,1 etc.

Comment: - coffeemath what is your calculation? Answer still is coming out wrong. Can you help?

Comment: I just did the Simpson calculation and got $-125.7332581$ so I agree with your result. The true value of the integral is about $-124.9963943$ according to doing a numerical integration. So it seems to me the answer for (c) in the box is too far off to be correct for simpson here.