# Need a guide how to solve Trapezoidal rule with integrals

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need some steps and the formula that i need to follow in order to solve trapezoidal rule exercises. I have the solution but i don't know how things works.

**Exercise**:
Use the trapezoidal rule (T) to approximate the integral $\int _0^1\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$ with 4 subintervals.

**Solution:**

[image]

Comment: Can you learn from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494710/290189 and show us some steps?

Comment: yes i'm adding my instructor's solution

Comment: Can you point out *where* you get stuck?

Comment: I haven't stuck yet. I need a guide what steps to follow because i am confused. I cannot study by looking at the solution

Comment: Then take a look at the formula

Comment: okay i am confused how he finds `x0,x1,x2,x3,x4` values. For example, how is `x2 = 2/4` ?

Comment: @csandreas1 He chooses the partition $P=[0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},1]$ of $[0,1]$.